# restarting MySQL on ubuntu after changing sql mode

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, sql-mode

I am getting an error in mysql

```
Expression #1 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'returntr_prod.tbl_customer_pod_uploads.id' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by
```

for which I found that I need to change the sql mode using

```
SET GLOBAL sql_mode=(SELECT REPLACE(@@sql_mode,'ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY',''));
```

I have executed the above in the mysql terminal and after executing this it is suggested to restart the mysql service. So I have come out of mysql terminal to ubuntu terminal and tried to execute

```
sudo restart mysql
```

I get an error message `sudo: restart: command not found`. Can someone help me understand why am I getting this error.

Comment: You don't need to restart after using `SET GLOBAL` to change that option. In fact, it will make your change revert to whatever is set in `/etc/my.cnf`.

Comment: I have seen other answers which say that it has to be restarted. I am confused now

Comment: If you edit the `/etc/my.cnf`, those changes won't take effect until you restart the mysqld server. Maybe that's what you read about. The settings in `/etc/my.cnf` are read only at startup. Then subsequently, you can change the settings with `SET GLOBAL` (most options can be changed dynamically, but not all). Then the next time you restart, any of those changes you made with `SET GLOBAL` are "lost" because the restart will read `/etc/my.cnf` again at startup.

Comment: So some people use `SET GLOBAL` _and_ also edit the `/etc/my.cnf` to the same value for the respective option, so the next restart will restore the desired setting.

Answer (score 2):

Try

`sudo systemctl restart mysql`

Or

`sudo service mysql restart`